# From 2 tables, get rows unique to each table

Tags: sql, t-sql

Starting with 2 tables, I want to get all rows with value in a certain column(cName) that is present on 1 table but not the other.  I want to do this for both tables.  I found a solution to use LEFT JOIN which gives me solution for 1 of the tables and I used UNION to combine.  Is this a good way to do this or is there a better way?

```
select * 
from College C1 LEFT JOIN myTestTable T1 on C1.cName = T1.cName
where T1.cName IS NULL
UNION
select *
from myTestTable T1 LEFT JOIN College C1 on T1.cName = C1.cName 
where C1.cName IS NULL
```

Comment: The set operator [`except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql) can do the same as what you achieved with a `left join ... is null`. Validate the performance to see which is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `full join` with a `where`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM College C1 FULL JOIN
     myTestTable T1
     ON C1.cName = T1.cName
WHERE T1.cName IS NULL OR C1.cName IS NULL;
```

Comment: Is this good performance for table with 100k + rows?

Comment: @bakalolo.. . . The performance should be fine, especially with indexes on `cName`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer anti-join (NOT EXISTS) operators rather than LEFT JOIN.  For one, if CName is not unique the left join produces multiple rows which the UNION must eliminate.

```
select * from College C1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTestTable T1 WHERE C1.cName = T1.cName)
 UNION
select * from myTestTable T1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM College C1     WHERE T1.cName = C1.cName);
```

If indexes aren't available on CName you'll have some table scans with either LEFT JOIN or the NOT EXISTS.

You could also do this:

```
select * from College
 union all
select * from myTestTable
 MINUS ( select * from College intersect select * from myTestTable );
```